# Is ma solution correct to this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}}}=3$$

My take: $$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}}}=3\implies {x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}}}=9$$
Thus: $$x+3=9\implies x=6$$

Did I do it right?

Comment: Yes, you did... **assuming** the sequence of infinite nested square roots converges finitely. Can you prove this?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to compute this limit is the following:

Let $x_1 = x $, and $x_n = \sqrt{x + x_n}$, for $n \geq 2$.  Then prove that the limit of the $x_n$'s exists by showing that the sequence is monotonic and bounded.

Then, we have that $L =  \sqrt{x + L}$ but $L =3$ so you get that $x = 6$.

Comment: Thank you man and good luck in your graduate studies :)))))

Answer (score 3):

You got the right answer. This is a recursive question. Take: $$u=\sqrt{x+u}$$ We know this is true because, if you evaluate it, it will come out to be: $u=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\dots}}}$ expanded to $\infty$.

We are given what $u$ is. It is $3$ according to the first equation. Thus, plugging it back in: $$3=\sqrt{x+3}$$ $$x=6$$

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Haters loooolol ^^